# How to print out a searchable list of numbers in java swing?

Tags: java, swing, numbers

What is the best way to show a finite amount of uneditable, searchable data(32bit numbers) in a `JPanel`?

E.G. If I have the numbers 32, 58 and 74 I would like to somehow go to the number 74 if I enter 74 in something like a `JTextField` and click a search button.

I was thinking about using a `JTextArea` for the data but I don't know if that would be my best option considering I also need to add some sort of search functionality.  I would also like it to be re-sizable and have the numbers in some sort of column like arrangement.  Any ideas how I should proceed would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "searchable"?

Comment: If I have the numbers 32, 58 and 74 I would like to somehow go to the number 74 if I enter 74 in something like a Jtextfield and click a search button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[JList](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) but with limited funcionalities with comparing to the [JTable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting), into [JScrollPane](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html)

Comment: Is a JList easily searchable?

Comment: @Grammin, not easy job and not confortable as built-in JTable's RowFilter

Comment: So your suggestion would be to go with the JTable?

Comment: your question is very vague, for me too, there are two searchable JComponents AutoComplete(d) JComboBox, or JTable, JTable is better for largiest data, AutoComplete(d) JComboBox for easy of use

Comment: I was thinking of a JComoBox before I'd even finished reading the question.  With the quoted data of 32, 58 & 74, it'd take just one keystroke (if the combo has focus) to go to any of the 3.  A filtered JTable is also a good idea for larger amounts of data.  Can you edit those suggestions into your answer (so I can up-vote, if nothing else)?

Comment: @Andrew Thompson thanks I vote for - without your up-vote, but edit my post by your idea,

Answer (score 1):

Use a JList, combined with JIDE's searchable widget for JList: http://www.jidesoft.com/products/oss.htm